# powershell query to check if the drive is empty

Tags: powershell, disk

So I have a query that scans through all the available disk drives:

```
$Disks = get-wmiobject Win32_LogicalDisk | ? {$_.drivetype -eq '3' -and $_.DeviceID -ne 'c:'} | % {get-psdrive $_.deviceid[0]} | select Root 

Foreach ($drive in $Disks)

{
//This tells me if a particular folder is present
$DriveLetter = Test-Path $drive -PathType Container| where-Object {$_.Name -like '*SQL*'} 

Write-Host "$driveletter"
}
```

What I wish to obtain the drive letter that contains no files and folders.

Is there a simple method to achieve this?

Comment: Check if `@(Get-ChildItem -Path $driveletter -Force).Count` is `0` or not

Comment: Thanks Mathias. I get the total count + 2 on each drive. For the drives that are empty, I still get a count of 2. Any particular reason why that value exists?

Comment: Try `@(Get-ChildItem -Path $drive.Root -Force).Count` and see what that gets ya. I had to add .Root to the variable to get it working properly.

Comment: and maybe check if there arent hidden or systemfiles. you can try without -force. `@(Get-ChildItem -Path $driveletter).Count`  [link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849800.aspx) quote: _Force: Allows the cmdlet to get items that cannot otherwise not be accessed by the user, such as hidden or system files. Implementation varies among providers. For more information, see about_Providers (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113250). Even when using the Force parameter, the cmdlet cannot override security restrictions._

Comment: Did add the root in my original query. Same result. Also checked for  hidden files or folders. None. Its a VM. I wonder if some default system files are added but not accessible at OS level

Comment: @LokeshGunjugnur - Just how did you check for hidden files or folders? It would seem quite likely for there to be both a `System Volume Information` and a `$Recycle.Bin`

Comment: Simplest answer is to run the command without the `Count` and see the output.

Comment: Yup. Its the recycle Bin and System Volume information. This has been great fellas. I thank you all for your time and effort.

Comment: Yup.. Some VMWARE files in there. All good now. Thanks all.